# Facebook post being duplicated multiple times on a page

Tags: facebook, post, random, duplication

I have an article posted on a Facebook Page.

However the article seems to keep reposting itself on the page at random intervals. Sometimes this will happen 3 or 4 times in a single day, and sometimes it won't happen at all. The post doesn't say it's being submitted by any application at the bottom like it would if it was.

It appears just as if a link has been pasted in the comment box, and submitted.

Any ideas what is causing this issue and how to stop it?

It's only one article that is causing the issue.

Cheers,
Thomas.

Comment: Your probably better off posting this on the Facebook forums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having looked at the graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/feed I discovered that it's being posted by an application called Notes.

No idea what it's for, but I have disabled its ability to post to the wall.

Will see if that stops the problem, and then tick this answer as final if that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with duplicate posts from a page showing up in an event (hosted by that page) over a 72 hour period, appearing at intervals of 4-5 hours. I eventually tracked it down to my Facebook app. When I went to the discussion section for the event on my phone, I saw that the post that had been repeatedly posting was listed as "will retry your post" because I had tried to post and gotten an error in my original attempt to post it. I chose "discard the post" and hopefully this will fix the issue.

It appears this may be an ongoing Facebook issue based on these two related posts

- ["Why am I repeatedly getting "will retry" messages on posts I shared days ago?"](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=10103550449602421)
- ["What does will retry your post mean?"](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=10204586210841706)